# How to add Dynamic Variable in VBA PowerQuery

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am connecting an excel workbook to a VBA macro through a power query. The macro should select the file within the user's directory that also matches the correct date on the file name.

The path should be first generated by the variable:

```
f = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data\details_" & Month([Date].Value) & "." & Day([Date].Value) & ".xlsx"
```

Then, the variable should be placed into the PowerQuery:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="PortalData", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(f), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table1_Table = Source{[Item=""Table1"",Kind=""Table""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table1_Table,{...})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
```

The File.Contents(f) searches for a file named '`f`' instead of the path. The `File.Contents()` originally contained a path in double-quotes but adding double quotes to f does not work.

Comment: You need to concatenate with `&`.

Comment: @BigBen I added it as File.Contents(""&f&"") but am getting an error for valid absolute path details &f&

Comment: First step. `Debug.Print` your concatenated string and examine in the Immediate Window.

Comment: @BigBen Ok so running Debug.Print f = path shows as True. Debug.Print path shows C:\Users\XXXXX\Downloads\V3.3 Automated Review File 1.28\Folder1\Portal Data\details_2.3.xlsx\ –

Comment: I guess I meant `Debug.Print` everything after `Formula:= _`, i.e. the actual M query, not just the path portion.

Comment: C:\Users\XXXXX\Downloads\V3.3 Aulet
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("&f&"), null, true),
    Table1_Table = Source{[Item="Table1",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table1_Table,{{...})
in
    #"Changed Type"
tomated Review File  1.28\VOC - Automated Review File\Portal Data\details_2.3.xlsx\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228222/discussion-between-joshk-and-bigben).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to replace:

```
File.Contents(""&f&"")
```

with

```
File.Contents(""" & f & """)
```

Thanks to @BigBen for the help!